# Jackson - Json to POJO With Multiple Entries

Tags: java, json, jackson

I know If the file User.json has

```
{
  "name" : { "first" : "Joe", "last" : "Sixpack" },
  "gender" : "MALE",
  "verified" : false,
  "userImage" : "Rm9vYmFyIQ=="
}
```

I can construct a single User object like this :

```
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("user.json"), User.class);
```

But how do I construct a list of objects if the file User.json has :

```
{
  "name" : { "first" : "Joe", "last" : "Sixpack" },
  "gender" : "MALE",
  "verified" : false,
  "userImage" : "Rm9vYmFyIQ=="
},
{
  "name" : { "first" : "Jane", "last" : "Austen" },
  "gender" : "FEMALE",
  "verified" : false,
  "userImage" : "DFREWEWE=="
}
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple ways: if you have a JSON array of these, you can do:

```
User[] users = mapper.readValue(json, User[].class);
```

or, if it is just a sequence of root level values you can do:

```
Iterator<User> it = mapper.readValues(json, User.class);
```

and iterate over values (add to a List or such)

Comment: from the code in the question, it's clear that 'json' is a File object, containing the JSON text

Comment: Correct -- I did not specify type since it can come from multiple sources (or even be JSON `byte[]` or `String`). @ImtiazAhmad check out Jackson javadocs for possible types to learn more.

Comment: I am facing just the opposite of this problem. I want to create a json file like user.json. with multiple root level values. But when I run the mapper.writeValue() method, it overwrites over older values. Can anyone help.

Comment: @ShashankGarg yes: ObjectMapper.writer().writeValues(dst) gives you `SequenceWriter` to do what you want