# De-serialize List of POJOs rather than a single one at a time

Tags: java, json, jackson

So I came across this tutorial for serializing a POJO to json and then de-serialize the json file back to the POJO. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

he uses these helpful methods which worked for me but only for a single POJO in the file:

```
//1. Convert Java object to JSON format
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), user);

//2. Convert JSON to Java object
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User.class);
```

How can I de-serialize a list of POJOs? My serialized file looks like the below:

```
[ {
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Wonder",
    "last" : "Woman"
  },
  "ssn" : "123-456-7890",
  "gender" : "FEMALE",
  "verified" : false
}, {
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Bat",
    "last" : "Man"
  },
  "ssn" : "321-456-0987",
  "gender" : "FEMALE",
  "verified" : true
}, {
  "name" : {
    "first" : "Super",
    "last" : "Man"
  },
  "ssn" : "321-654-1111",
  "gender" : "FEMALE",
  "verified" : true
} ]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jackson - Json to POJO With Multiple Entries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045836/jackson-json-to-pojo-with-multiple-entries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One option (probably the easiest) is to define a class that contains a list of `User`s:

   ```
   public class Users
   {
     public User[] users;
   }
   ```

   Then performing

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   Users users = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), Users.class);
   ```
2. Another option would be to iterate over the json array, and capture each element of the array of users, then use `ObjectMapper.readValue(String content, Class<T> valueType)`, like so:

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   InputStream stream = new FileInputStream("c:\\user.json");
   User user;

   JsonNode json = mapper.readTree(stream);

   //NOTE: calling json.isArray() should return true.
   for (JsonNode userJson : json)
   {
     user = mapper.readValue(userJson, User.class);
     // use the constructed user...
   }
   ```

   **Note**: I haven't tested the above, so let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Can you elaborate on option 2? Please provide a code example as I am new to Java. Thank you.

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad elaborated.

Comment: What is the InputStream from? Is it a jackson library or are you using java.io ? Also json.getElements() has a compilation error:   `The method getElements() is undefined for the type JsonNode`

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad Yes, the `InputStream` is out of `java.io`. I added a note, and removed the call to `getElements` entirely.

Comment: `readValue()` is not compiling. It gives me the error:  The method readValues(JsonParser, ResolvedType) in the type ObjectMapper is not applicable for the arguments (JsonNode, Class<User>). Eclipse suggest, to change method call to `readValues()` but that doesnt work either.

Comment: @ImtiazAhmad The API claims that [readValue(JsonNode, Class<T>)](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode,%20java.lang.Class)) exists, so I'm not sure why you're getting that.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmh? Have you tried:

```
User[] users = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json"), User[].class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your top level class, you have an array of people.  something like this

```
    class People {
    public List<Person> persons;
}
```