# JSON Array Of Entries to POJO

Tags: java, arrays, json, gson

I have a JSON file that has multiple entries inside of an array. Each of those entries needs to be mapped to a java object. Here is the JSON string I am testing with (http://jsonlint.com/ validated the JSON below, but I had to erase all of the escape characters which I use in the actual Java test),

```
  [{
    "LocId":99,
    "typeId":99,
    "name":"foo",
    "parentId":99,
    "geoCode":
    {
      "type":"foo",
      "coordinates":
      [{
        "latitude":99.0,
        "longitude":99.0
      }]
    }
  ,
    "LocId":8,
    "typeId":99,
    "name":"foo",
    "parentId":99,
    "geoCode":
    {
      "type":"foo",
      "coordinates":
      [{
        "latitude":99.0,
        "longitude":99.0
      }]
    }
  }]
```

I read this string in like this,

```
    String str = "The JSON string shown above";
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    LocIdClass[] locations = new Gson().fromJson(br, LocIdClass[].class);
```

But the size of my locations array is always one and only the last entry in the JSON string is stored.

```
    for(int i=0; i<locations.length; i++)
        System.out.println(locations[i]);

    System.out.println("The size of the array is " + locations.length);
```

I'm not sure why only the last entry in the JSON string would be retrieved but the others are skipped. I referred to this SO post to figure out the POJO array [Jackson - Json to POJO With Multiple Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045836/jackson-json-to-pojo-with-multiple-entries).

Comment: Is your data correct? It seems to be missing a `{` when the second object starts.

Comment: It was successfully validated as proper JSON in http://jsonlint.com/. And I can tell by looking at it that it's two entities inside a JSON array and the syntax looks correct to me.

Comment: Look at the formatted json in the jsonlint text area: a whole section of the original "json" is removed.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't notice that. Where is the problem though.

Comment: How would you rewrite this properly because it looks like it's in the needed format for an array with two objects.

Comment: Replace the middle `,` with `} , {` and it will appear correctly in jsonlint.

Comment: I'm confused on this though. If you look at my array under the key "coordinates" I have "latitude" and "longitude" separated by a comma i.e., they're not enclosed in their own brackets. Why would it be any different for the outermost array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have an error in your current json payload, try this:

```
    [
        {
            "LocId": 99,
            "typeId": 99,
            "name": "foo",
            "parentId": 99,
            "geoCode": {
                "type": "foo",
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "latitude": 99,
                        "longitude": 99
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "LocId": 8,
            "typeId": 99,
            "name": "foo",
            "parentId": 99,
            "geoCode": {
                "type": "foo",
                "coordinates": [
                    {
                        "latitude": 99,
                        "longitude": 99
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

Edit: To avoid this issue in the future, you can use jsonlint.com to check your json. Make sure it is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I'm confused on this though. If you look at my array under the key "coordinates" I have "latitude" and "longitude" separated by a comma i.e., they're not enclosed in their own brackets. Why would it be any different for the outermost array?

Comment: latitude and longitude are within the same object. If you had a list of latitude of longitude objects, it would behave the same way as you location array.

Comment: So then this is a special case kind of when you have an outermost array of the initial objects? I guess this means there isn't a grand/root object that's not shown. I hope that made sense...